# How to close File Explorer in `selenium webdriver`

Tags: python, selenium

Now i am trying to file upload using a selenium webdriver.

I am able to upload files sucessfully, however, I am not able to close file explorer using `esc`.
I have used `switch_to` method to switch the window then attempt to close it, but it does not work either.
Is there any way to close file explorer in selenium webdriver?

Below is my codes

```
docs = [
  'DriversLicense',
  'CarRegistration',
  'Insurance',
  'BizCertificate'
]

tester_dir_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))
source_dir_path = os.path.join(tester_dir_path, 'source')
driver_dir_path = os.path.join(source_dir_path, 'driver')

for idx, doc in enumerate(docs):
  path = os.path.join(driver_dir_path, f"{str( int(idx) + 1 )}.jpg")

  doc_ele = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.file-list li[data-prefix="' + doc + '"]')
  doc_ele.click()

  time.sleep(1)
  self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])
  webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()

  file_input = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.file-list li[data-prefix="' + doc + '"] input[name="driver-doc"]')
  file_input.send_keys(path)

  time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: what 'File Explorer' ?

Comment: can you share your html part for the same?

Comment: why do you want to close the file explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will Close any current window using python with Selenium WebDriver

Step 1: Install and import pyatspi2 package

Step 2: Use this Function in your code.

```
import pyatspi
def CloseWindow():

pyatspi.Registry.generateKeyboardEvent(64, None, pyatspi.KEY_PRESS)
pyatspi.Registry.generateKeyboardEvent(70, None, pyatspi.KEY_PRESSRELEASE)
pyatspi.Registry.generateKeyboardEvent(64, None, pyatspi.KEY_RELEASE)
```

Step 3: Call this function where you want to close the attachment window or any window.

```
attachbtn = driver.find_element_by_id(":nx")
attachbtn.click() 

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=\"file\"]").send_keys("file path")

CloseWindow() #it will call the function and close the currently opened window
```